# CentOS 7 install rh-php73

Tags: centos, php

I am using CentOS7 with Virtualmin for my webserver.
After some Google searches i keep on getting documentation about remi repositories. But i am using RH, as suggested by Virtualmin.
I have installed multiple PHP versions using the virtualmin documentation.

For some testing i need PHP 7.3 installed but for some reason the command line keeps telling me it is not available.
"rh-php73 not available"

However... according to this link: https://cbs.centos.org/koji/buildinfo?buildID=27107 it should be available.

How can i get this working without having to reinstall everything and start using remi.

Answer (score 2):

**rh-php73** is not yet released as stable, only part of **RHSCL 3.4 Beta**

- For **RHEL 7** users in the **rhel-server-rhscl-7-beta-rpms** channel: rh-php73 packages
- For **CentOS 7** users in the **centos-sclo-rh-testing** repository: rh-php73 packages
- Additional packages in the **centos-sclo-sclo-testing** repository: sclo-php73 packages